# How to Revert Changes: destroy devise_invitabe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise-invitable

I tried devise_invitable and added this to an existing MODEL

```
rails generate devise_invitable MODEL
```

It added some files, changes to db [migration files],..
I don't need it anymore. so i thought to remove it. In rails there is

```
rails destroy ...
```

to remove model or controller. How can i revert back the changes made by the rails generate devise_invitable?

Comment: not sure but may be `rails destroy devise_invitable MODEL` work . i know that's illogical but sometime do the trick ;)

Comment: @NitinJ: I tried it already! Didn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If u have added devise_invitable on a model say `User`

then to destroy u should do

```
$ rails destroy devise_invitable User
```

and then

```
$ rails destroy devise_invitable:install
```

Comment: Wouldnt you do a migration rollback and then destroy? because I need to do the same sort of thing

Comment: yes ofcourse if u dont need invitation related fields u should remove them first by rolling back...